# How do I get 'psql' (from pgadmin4) installed on Fedora 34?

Tags: psql, fedora, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am attempting to install '**pgadmin4**' on a Fedora 34 VM (AWS AMI EC2), but it is not installing '**psql**'

---

**I ran these commands:**

```
sudo rpm -i https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/yum/pgadmin4-fedora-repo-2-1.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install pgadmin4-desktop
```

and `psql` is no where to be found

I ran:  `sudo find / -type f -name psql`, and nothing was found.

How do I get `psql` installed on Fedora 34?

I do not want to install the server / database.  I just need 'psql' on the system.  I do not need or want the web components.

---

I have lost about three hours with this, extremely frustrated.

I have searched and searched, tried a number of things.

It will be a miracle if I can get this working, if anyone has any ideas or has actually installed `pgadmin4-desktop` successfully or found a way to get `psql` onto a system (without installing the database software).

I just need the psql client.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo yum install postgresql
```

`pgadmin4-desktop` sounds like GUI to me. If you need server it's in `postgresql-server`

Comment: Have you tried this successfully and this works?  I'm not looking for the server, just the client and to get 'psql' installed.

Comment: I don't see that 'sudo yum install postgresql' will work.  I'm not looking for the server.  Just 'psql' that comes with 'padmin4'.  This response offers nothing of value.

Comment: Simple : `sudo dnf provides psql` .... The replies are e.g.  "`postgresql`[version]" || /usr/bin/psql and /usr/pgsql-13/bin/psql